# I need assistantance with this python code

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need help with this code since I'm getting an error and I don't know how to fix it. I'm new to coding and I want to learn how to code after I get this problem figured out. I am currently running the code on https://replit.com and I kept on getting this error if your able to figure it out that would be great!

code:

```
import discord
import os
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Style
import requests
import time
from colorama import Fore
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
token = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

def Cls():
os.system('cls')
Cls()
b = Style.BRIGHT
message = input("What do you want to say in the embed? ")
Cls() 

token = "token""

 Cls()


 b = Style.BRIGHT
 print(f"""
 {b+Fore.GREEN}
██      ██ ███████     ███    ███  █████  ███████ ███████ ██████  ███    ███ 
 ██      ██ ██          ████  ████ ██   ██ ██      ██      ██   ██  
 ████  ████ 
██      ██ █████       ██ ████ ██ ███████ ███████ ███████ ██   ██ ██ ████ ██ 
██      ██ ██          ██  ██  ██ ██   ██      ██      ██ ██   ██  
██  ██  ██ 
███████ ██ ███████     ██      ██ ██   ██ ███████ ███████ ██████  ██      ██



{b+Fore.BLUE} > {Fore.RESET}MASS DM
{b+Fore.BLUE} > {Fore.RESET}Creator: watch#0001
""")

watch = discord.Client()


@watch.event
async def on_connect():
for user in watch.user.friends:
try:
  
  watchy = discord.Embed(color= discord.Color(0x2f3136))
  watchy.set_author(name="join discord.gg/HeKbnh57 ")
  watchy.add_field(name="discord.gg/HeKbnh57",value=message)
  watchy.set_image(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/811724526915289109/830113315405561896/image0.jpg")
  time.sleep(.1)
  await user.send(embed=watchy)
  await user.send("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixyIfsFZGg4")
  time.sleep(.1)
  print(f'messaged:' + Fore.GREEN + f' {user.name}')
except:
   print(f"couldnt message: {user.name}")
   print(f"Directed messaged all users friends")


 watch.run(token, bot=False)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 300, 
in static_login
data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 254, 
in request
raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 61, in <module>
watch.run(token, bot=False)
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 
723, in run
return future.result()
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 
702, in runner
await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 
665, 
in start
await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 
511, 
in login
await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 304, 
in static_login
raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
```

Comment: The error is pretty much self-explanatory: `discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.`

Comment: I assume `token = "token"` is an example, and that the actual `token` is a valid one, since I'd think literally `"token"` would be totally invalid. How are you getting the actual `token` value?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the variable `token = "token""` should be using the [token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEnYz.png) not "token", also it has an extra `"`. If you don't wanna use a variable use (in your case) `watch.run("token")`, with the token beetween the inverted commas, like this: `watch.run("1375ioda8da541f7ds984a8asd-ASMSJBNDdasdsKAs")`.
And you code from `watch = discord.Client()` to `watch.run(token, bot=False)` is commented.